# Is it possible to adjust/modify simultaneously the Remote Config settings for multiple Firebase projects?

Tags: firebase-remote-config

Assuming that we have multiple Firebase projects for multiple apps using the same software, is it possible to modify or adjust the Remote Config settings of all the Firebase projects simultaneously?

For instance if a new feature is developed for the existing software. Adjustments can be made in each individual Firebase project, but is there a solution to push a new setting to all in only one single step?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it from the Firebase console, but you can write a simple script which uses the Remote Config REST API - https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-rest - where you have complete control on how you want to publish changes & in which all projects.